# Return multiple rows with various column data using Vlookup or INDEX-MATCH

Tags: excel, vlookup

Now I have an excel file with 2 sheets, I need to pull some data from sheet1 to sheet2, based on a single criterion - Text in Column A from sheet1 contains certain text string from A2 from sheet2. In the meantime, I also have to pull data from other columns from those rows where the text string is found. However, Vlookup only returns the first instance. Since the file is confidential, I created a moackup for this.

Sheet1

```
Classes Taken   Name    Gender  Age

Math,Physics,Chemistry, Literature  Joseph  Male    16

Chinese, History, Philosophy, Politics  Alice   Female  17

Philosophy, Math, Physics   Erica   Female  16

Chinese, Biology, Statistics    Evan    Male    18
```

Sheet2

```
Philosophy  (Lookup)

Name    Gender  Age
```

What if I want the information of people who have taken philosophy class displayed in sheet2.

Thank you!!

Comment: If you need all instances, you would need VBA. Formula is not sufficient.

Comment: I don't really know about VBA, is there any code that could be apply on this case directly?

Comment: Consider using a pivot table.

Comment: Then mock up some data that is in the same format and show what your expected outcome would be with that mock data.

Comment: I have already created a mockup here, please help me!

Comment: Is "Math, Physics, Chemisty, Literature" all in the same cell, in column A?

Comment: `already created a mockup here, please help me` you're new here but please know that at SO, we expect you to show effort before you ask for help.

Comment: Bruce, yes they are in the same cell using a delimiter. In my original formula I used wild card to cope with that.

Comment: You can use the standard filter to do this. If you want formulas they will be array type formulas. If the dataset ID large it will slow down the occupation times and may even crash excel. I would recommend an advanced filter.

Answer (score 0):

### NON-ARRAY SOLUTION

**Sheet1**
- Enter table data on `Sheet1` as shown here:
[Sheet1 Thumbnail Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AKTSQ.png)

**Sheet2**
- Cell `A1` contains the lookup value: *Philosophy*.
- Cells `A2:C2` contain the header row data: `Name` `Gender`    `Age`
- In cell `A3`, insert this formula:
`=INDEX(Sheet1!$A2:$D2,MATCH("*"&$A$1&"*",Sheet1!$A2:$A2,0),MATCH(A$2,Sheet1!$A$1:$D$1,0))`
- Press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.
- Copy across to `C3`, then down to `C6` to get the result shown here:
[Sheet2 Thumbnail Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iaq8I.png)

Answer (score 0):

### ARRAY SOLUTION

**Sheet1**
- Enter table data on `Sheet1` as shown here:
[Sheet1 Thumbnail Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AKTSQ.png)

**Sheet2**
- Cell `A1` contains the lookup value: *Philosophy*.
- Cells `A2:C2` contain the header row data: `Name` `Gender`    `Age`
- In cell `A3`, insert this formula:
`=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!B$2:B$5,SMALL(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($A$1,Sheet1!$A$2:$A$5)),ROW(Sheet1!B$2:B$5)-ROW(Sheet1!B$2)+1),ROWS(Sheet1!$1:1))),"")`
- Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>.
- Copy across to `C3`, then down to `C6` to get the result shown here:
[Sheet2 Thumbnail Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Do1vk.png)

**Please Note**
- This formula contains the `IFERROR` function, which will only work in Excel for PC 2007 or newer. It will also work in Excel for Mac 2011 or newer (according to Microsoft's documentation).
- This formula is also an `ARRAY`, which may slow things down if you're working with a large dataset.
- Each time you edit this formula, reconfirm by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>.